# Grails find entries with specific minute

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I have several domain classes which generate large data sets each minute. Something like this:

```
class Foo{
    String name
    Date received
    int value
}
```

I want to accomplish the same result set this MySQL query returns:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE received BETWEEN ? AND ? AND MINUTE(received) = ?
```

Is this possible using a NamedQuery or findAllBy... ?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130921/grails-gorm-select-as) question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Some arbitrarily chosen values for the query placeholders
Date minReceived = new Date()
Date maxReceived = minReceived + 5    
Integer minute = 0

Foo.findAll( 
    "from Foo where received between :min and :max and minute(received) = :minute", 
    [min: minReceived, max: maxReceived, minute: minute])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since HQL does provide a minute function, I was able to find a solution by myself. Since Foo is part of many other classes I wanted a common method for all of them. Anyway, here's the solution for Foo and friends:

```
clazz.executeQuery(
'from ' + clazz.getSimpleName() + ' c where c.received between :from and :to 
and minute(received) = :period', [from:d1, to:d2, period:0])
```

Thanks anyway Don.

Comment: I didn't know HQL provides a minute function, I've updated my answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid HQL, you can use [sqlRestriction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29) in a Criteria. It doesn't support parameters, though.